# Requesting permissions from user programmatically?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I want to add the feature of giving the user the list of permissions to approve just after opening the app for the first time.

I read from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) article regarding how to do this.

But I still have some queries regarding this, to make this feature of my app truly dynamic:

- How to read from manifest file the list of required permission?
  (This to avoid explicit hard-coded verification of each required
  permissions)
- How to *programatically* classify these permissions as *NORMAL* and *DANGEROUS*, since I need to explicitly ask the user only when the permission is of *dangerous* kind? (As per documentation, *normal* permissions are automatically granted by the OS without requesting the user)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check every time weather permission is granted or not to your app when you want to perform some operation related to that permissions.

Because user may disable that permission from settings any time.

## **Dangerous permissions and permission groups:**

**CALENDAR**

```
READ_CALENDAR
WRITE_CALENDAR
```

**CALL_LOG**

```
READ_CALL_LOG 
WRITE_CALL_LOG 
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

**CAMERA**

```
CAMERA
```

**CONTACTS**

```
READ_CONTACTS
WRITE_CONTACTS
GET_ACCOUNTS
```

**LOCATION**

```
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

**MICROPHONE**

```
RECORD_AUDIO
```

**PHONE**

```
READ_PHONE_STATE
READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
CALL_PHONE
ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS
ADD_VOICEMAIL
USE_SIP
```

**SENSORS**

```
BODY_SENSORS
```

**SMS**

```
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
RECEIVE_MMS
```

**STORAGE**

```
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Source [Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)

## **Normal Permissions:**

```
ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
BLUETOOTH
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
BROADCAST_STICKY
CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
DISABLE_KEYGUARD
EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
FOREGROUND_SERVICE
GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
INSTALL_SHORTCUT
INTERNET
KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
MANAGE_OWN_CALLS
MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
NFC
READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
READ_SYNC_STATS
RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
REORDER_TASKS
REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND
REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND
REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES
REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
SET_ALARM
SET_WALLPAPER
SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
TRANSMIT_IR
USE_FINGERPRINT
VIBRATE
WAKE_LOCK
WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
```

Source [Normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal_permissions)

## **Get list of required permission programmatically:**

```
public void readPermission()
{
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        if (info.requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (String p : info.requestedPermissions) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission : " + p);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It was very useful. However, can you please respond to my queries as well?

Comment: Thanks a ton :) So amongst these permissions, if I use the code described in the link I mentioned, the dialog would not pop up for a normal permission right? Only for dangerous permissions would a dialog be shown to the user, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you have to ask to user for dangerous permission every time when you required if not granted already.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no way to read all the permissions from the manifest programmatically. However, since you already have them listed in the Manifest before releasing your APK, you already know which permissions you need to ask for. Don't you?

Let's say you have READ_PHONE_STATE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest, you can add this in your permission check in your MainActivity.java:

```
ArrayList<String> arrPerm = new ArrayList<>();
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    arrPerm.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
}
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    arrPerm.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if(!arrPerm.isEmpty()) {
    String[] permissions = new String[arrPerm.size()];
    permissions = arrPerm.toArray(permissions);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
}
```

This will trigger permission requests, for both WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_PHONE_STATE, one after the other. To check which permissions where granted, do this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    String permission = permissions[i];
                    if(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.equals(permission)) {
                        if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // you now have permission
                        }
                    }
                    if(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.equals(permission)) {
                        if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // you now have permission
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the permissions defined in manifest with 
<uses-permission android:name="..."/>
will automatically work for android devices with API level below 23. For devices above android (6.0), you will have to check for permissions at runtime.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html
this link has a list of dangerous permissions

Answer (score 0):

Run time permissions are added in Android from Android 6.0 (API level 23), before that permissions should only be defined in manifest. But is Android 6 and greater you need to take run time permission (danger) from user right before perform task.

From documentation included in question

> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you
>   have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires
>   that permission.

So if you are performing a task which require danger permission so must ask user to take that, else it will throw a run time exception.

You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html) for taking permissions in best way

Comment: Yes I am aware of the first part, but my question is how to dynamically read these permissions from manifest and how to *classify* them programmatically?

Comment: What documentation teaches, is to take permission by hard coding them in code before performing that task which require those permissions. What you want, read all permissions from manifest and take them form user in a loop ? I don't know how our app smartly know, what permission I should ask now form user before performing the specific task